# Envers Pre/PostCollection Listener

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

I use Hibernate Envers with conditional logging. The documentation describes quite well how this can be done (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#d5e4449). At 2nd item, it says you have to subclass the appropriate listeners.. The purpose of the three listeners EnversPostDeleteEventListener, EnversPostInsertEventListener and EnversPostUpdateEventListener is clear to me.

However, I am not quite clear what exactly is the purpose of the other three listeners EnversPreCollectionUpdateEventListener, EnversPreCollectionRemoveEventListener and EnversPostCollectionRecreateEventListener? When should I configure them? Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's when you have persistent collections, e.g. fields of type `List<String>`, or `Set<EmbeddedComponent>`.